# Filter, Option or FlatMap in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter

I have next code in Spark:

```
dsPhs.filter(filter(_))
.map(convert)
.coalesce(partitions)
.filter(additionalFilter.IsValid(_))
```

At *convert* function I get more complex object - MyObject, so I need to prefilter basic object. I have 3 options:

1. Make map return option(MyObject) and filter it at additionalFilter
2. Replace map with flatMap and return empty array when filtered
3. Use filter before map function, to filter out RawObject, before converting it to MyObject.

Now I am go with option 3. But may be 1 or 2 is more preferable?

Comment: I like option 3 better than the other ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for option 2, you mean have convert return an empty array, there's another option: have convert return an `Option[MyObject]` and use `flatMap` instead of `map`. This has the best of options 1 and 2. Without knowing more about your use case, I can't say for sure whether this is better than option 3, but here are some considerations:

1. Should `convert` contain input validation logic? If so, consider modifying it to return an `Option`.

   - If `convert` is used, or will be used, in other places, could they benefit from this validation?
   - As a side note, this might be a good time to consider what `convert` currently does when passed an invalid argument.
2. Can you easily change `convert` and its signature? If not, consider using a `filter`.

Comment: if convert will return Option[MyObject] than what would be argument for flatMap? That's interesting. What is the key point here to choose between flatMap(convert) and filter(preFilter(_)).map(convert)? Assuming that we filter about 5 percent of all data?

Comment: @jk1 Sure, this is just another example of how Scala treats options like lists. As for which to choose, I'd say it depends mainly on whether `convert` should contain input validation logic. See my updated answer.